# runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit, fatal error: stack overflow on printing a nested struct

Tags: go, struct, stack, stack-overflow, panic

I have a nested struct.

```
type ConfigOne struct {
    // Daemon section from config file.
    Daemon daemon
}
type daemon struct {
    Loglevel int
    Logfile string
}
```

And I have a `String() string` method on that type, which I am trying to return the nested struct elements as

```
func (c ConfigOne)String()  string{
    return fmt.Sprintf("%+v\n", c)
}
```

When I am trying to print it as

```
c := &modules.ConfigOne{}
c.Daemon.Loglevel = 1
c.Daemon.Logfile = "/tmp/test.log"
modules.Logger.Infoln(c.String())
```

I am getting the error

> runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit
>   fatal error: stack overflow
>
> runtime stack:
>   runtime.throw(0x6ea3b7, 0xe)
>   ...

After going through the error, I could see repeated lines similar to the below one

> modules/structs.go:31 +0x77 fp=0xc440100398 sp=0xc440100328
>   go-consume/modules.(*ConfigOne).String(0xc42abcb4e0, 0x70bc08, 0xc42abd6300)
>   :1 +0x64 fp=0xc4401003d8 sp=0xc440100398
>   fmt.(*pp).handleMethods(0xc42abd6300, 0xc400000076, 0x410301)

and finally, before dying,

> modules/structs.go:31 +0xc0 fp=0xc440103d18 sp=0xc440103ca8
>   ...additional frames elided...
>
> goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:
>   runtime.goexit()

which I believe is caused by going into some infinite recursion.

I tried my luck to find the cause and reached [here](https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew/issues/45), which I believe is the same issue. However I couldn't understand the explanation in that thread.

If I try to print the individual nested struct as

```
func (c ConfigOne)String() string{
    //return fmt.Sprintf("%+v\n", c.Daemon.Loglevel)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%+v\n", c.Daemon)
}
```

it is working fine, and log shows the fields as

```
2017/03/05 01:28:25 go-consume.go:38: INFO: {Loglevel:1 Logfile:/tmp/test.log}
```

Can someone kindly explain how the former `String()` method is resulting in an infinite recursion and a stackoverflow, and what is the best way to overcome this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `%v` and `%+v` formats use the value of `String()` if the type implements it. Therefore, using `%+v` on a type within the `String()` function for that type causes infinite recursion. Instead of using `%+v` in the `String()` function, you'll have to construct your own string, showing the contents of the structure in whatever way you see fit.

Comment: Thank you @andy-schweig.