# How to printed type bebore change type of String method

Tags: go

I cannot call Print on a type before change string method that has a String method inside the type's String method:

```
type book struct{
  id int
  r relateF
  //Or can be delare as r relateF
}
type relateF struct{
  handle int
  grade float64
  name string
}
func(b book) String() string{
  fmt.Println(b)//<=I want to print it before change String method
  return fmt.Sprintf(b.r.name)
}
func main(){
  b1:= book{456,relateF{5,48.2,"History of the world"}}
  fmt.Println(b1)
}
```

it make a loop

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42600920/runtime-goroutine-stack-exceeds-1000000000-byte-limit-fatal-error-stack-overf

Answer (score 2):

One way is to declare a new temporary type with the same exact structure a `book` and then convert the `book` instance to this new type.

```
func (b book) String() string {
    type temp book       // same structure but no methods
    fmt.Println(temp(b)) // convert book to temp
    return fmt.Sprintf(b.r.name)
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/3ebFhptJLxj

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new type based on `book` that does not override the String() function:

```
func(b book) String() string{
  type temp book
  fmt.Println(temp(b))
  return fmt.Sprintf(b.r.name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This results in recursive calls. When you call `Println`, it actually calls the `String` method of the instance. Once you call `Println` in `String`, it will inevitably lead to infinite recursion.

If you want to print it before change `String` method, just comment out `String` and then print again.